# Freeman Chain Code in Java

Tags: java, arrays, chain

Okay, hopefully this makes more sense. I have an array hard coded with only 1s and 0s. I am trying to write a function that reads each element to see if it is a 0 or 1. If it is a 1, it will execute another function and then change that 1 to a 0 so that it is not read again. I have it printing simply as a placeholder for the other function I will be implementing later. I'm having trouble getting the findfirst1 function to check every element in the array. I have tried putting the incrementors for i and k in different places within the flow of the code but nothing I have tried gets me the correct output.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] testarray = {{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}};

    findfirst1(testarray);
}

public static void findfirst1(int[][] array1) 
{
    int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 7;k++)
        {
            value = array1[i][k];
            if(value == 1)
            {
                System.out.println(value);
                array1[i][k] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please add only necessary information.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you're trying to accomplish, but there are some obvious errors. The worst one is the use of hardcoded array bounds when you should be using `<array>.length` instead.  `findfirst1` has what looks like the wrong bounds in the loops so it's not examining the whole array.  Also `outline7` and `outline8` don't actually do anything. Are these just not yet implemented? Are you asking us to finish the work?

Comment: I don't ask people to do my work for me, otherwise I won't learn anything. I just need someone with a fresh pair of eyes to look at my code and tell me why what I'm trying to do isn't working.

Comment: @LalitVerma I'm sorry, most posts I've read on this site complain that there is not enough information.

Comment: "_I'm having trouble getting the findfirst1 function to check every element in the array_" Stop using hard coded loop sizes. Instead do something like `for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { for(int k = 0; k < array1[i].length; k++) { value = array1[i][k]; } }` to iterate all elements.

Comment: Again, I don't have a choice but to have it hard coded, it has to be specific values and of a specific size because it is representing a very basic picture. The end program will be a basic version of Freeman's Chain Code which uses counter clockwise directions, 0 through 7 in order to find the next 1 in the array. The issue isn't the array being hard coded, it is getting the findfirst1 method to find the first iteration of 1 in the array so that it can start the Freeman function that I haven't even started writing yet because I'm stuck on the search method for the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after starting completely over and writing it all from scratch I figured it out. The array.length was right all along. I had trouble wrapping my head around it because I was so focused on the idea of the "image".

Edit: I just found an error where it wouldn't print the last line for array1, so I just added an extra row of 0s and it worked.

```
public class ChainCodeClass {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] array1 = {{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}**,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}**};

    int[][] array2 = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

    System.out.print("First Image");
    print(array1);
    findfirst1(array1);
    print(array1);

    System.out.print("Second Image");
    print(array2);
    outline8(array2);
}

public static void findfirst1(int[][] array) 
{
    int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
        {
            value = array[i][k];
            if(value == 1)
            {
                System.out.print(value + "  ");
                array[i][k] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void print(int[][] array)
{
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) // print function for the array using incrementors
{
    System.out.print("\n");

    for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[i][k] + "    ");
    }
}
    System.out.println();
}
 }
```